# PHP - All scripts within specific directory to have same include path

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way to have all scripts within a directory use the same include path in php?

Lets say I have multiple applications. I would like like each application directory to have separate include paths.

Example:

App_1/

```
 config.php
 directory/
 ---- page.php
 ---- ajax.php // How do I write include('config.php') instead of '../config.php'
 ---- sub_directory/
 -------- ajax.php // How do I write include('config.php') instead of '../../config.php'
```

App_2/

```
 config.php
 directory/
 ---- page.php
 ---- ajax.php // How do I write include('config.php') instead of '../config.php'
 ---- sub_directory/
 -------- ajax.php // How do I write include('config.php') instead of '../../config.php'
```

Comment: What's the reason for that? Using include paths makes applications fragile and configuration-dependant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) setting in your `php.ini`.

Just add an entry by appending `:/your/path` to the setting, e.g

```
include_path=".:/php/includes"
// becomes
include_path=".:/php/includes:/var/www/my_website/includes"
```

---

You may also use [`set_include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to have a setting scoped to your script file.

Comment: Will the script just select the "closest"' one?

Comment: It will try each path one by one until it finds a file with the correct name.

Comment: Then in my example, if I were to use...
include_path=".:App_1_path:App_2_path"
and call a config from deep within application 2, it would utilize application 1's config. Correct?

Comment: Yes it will. However, you may use [`set_include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to have a settings scoped to your script file. Edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constant absolute path for config

```
include(PATH_TO_CONFIG.'config.php')
```